# clojure make change to vector of maps

Tags: clojure

```
(def tables
    [{:table "A" :occupied false :party nil} 
     {:table "B" :occupied false :party nil}
     {:table "C" :occupied false :party nil}])
```

1) How do I make a change to a single map with a vector?

ex. set :occupied = true where :table= "C"

2) What about updating all map values?
ex. set :occupied = false for all maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(map (fn [t] (if (= (:table t) "C") (assoc t :occupied true) t)) tables)`

`(map #(assoc % :occupied false) tables)`

Note that these will not change your tables, because they are immutable data structures, this code will instead return a new sequence of tables with the differences you describe.